# PHP: Check whether ID is from Vimeo or YouTube

Tags: php, youtube, vimeo

Is it possible in PHP to distinguish the different between a Vimeo ID (129565826) and a YouTube ID (Bo3bkdYHp_M)? They are both quite different, but wasn't sure the best way for PHP to know the difference? If I was using the full URLs, I could've done something like:

```
if (stripos($url,'youtube.com') === false) {
    //must be vimeo
} else {
    //is youtube
}
```

Any thoughts or help? Perhaps I could use `is_numeric`?

Thanks,
R

Comment: That is absolutly not a safe way to process that. You will never know when Vimeo or Facebook change their ID structure and both go with big int or string. Unfortunatly you should find a way to get the full URL of the service.

Answer (score 5):

### Regarding Youtube video ids

From a youtube staff member:

> We don't make any public guarantees about the format for video ids.

and

> If you need to validate that random user input corresponds to a valid
>   video id, I'd recommend doing an empirical test. Attempt to access http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID

taken from this answer:
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/54448
referencing this source:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/youtube-api-gdata/maM-h-zKPZc/PJDlDWv77TEJ

### Regarding Vimeo video ids

To the question:

> Will the Vimeo identification always be purely a number?

A vimeo staff member answered:

> The video ID will always be a numerical value, we have no plans in our immediate future to change this fundamental building block of the site :)

source: https://vimeo.com/forums/api/topic:267078

### Conclusion

- A non-numeric id can not point to a Vimeo video.
- There is no reliable way to ensure that a numeric id belongs to one service or the other.

Your best chance would be to query the API of each service to check for the existence of a video using the requested id.

Answer (score 0):

`strlen` and `is_numeric` would be my guess. But don't make it too hard for you to change, since the id format can change whenever.

```
if(strlen($video_id) == 11 && !is_numeric($video_id)){
    //YouTube
}else{
    //Vimeo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Vimeo url conatins only numbers then you can do something like this:

```
// $url constains the full url to the video, for youtube it would be like this $url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="
if(ctype_digit($id) && filter_var($url.$id, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) != FALSE){
   echo 'This is Vimeo url';
}else if(filter_var($url.$id, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) != FALSE) {
   echo 'This youtube url';
}
```

For safety reason we are using "Filter Validator" to check if the url is valid, just in case they would change the url construction

Answer (score 0):

I have used only `video ID` to determinate which embed block to implement

```
if(is_numeric($video_id)) {
    // print out VIMEO embed view block with $video_id
} else {
    // print out YOUTUBE embed view block with $video_id
}
```